# Correspondence between R's caret knnImpute and Python's sklearn.impute KNNImputer results

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, r-caret, knn

I am trying to replicate a machine learning process across different programming platforms but I am getting different imputed values from R Caret's preProcessing function compared to python's sklearn process. Using the example dataset and process below:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(197)
simulated.ds <- data.frame(
  var1 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.05),
  var2 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.4),
  var3 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.2),
  var4 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.03),
  var5 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.7),
  var6 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.1),
  var7 = rbinom(n=10000, size=1, prob=0.2)
)


set.seed(50)
ind1 <- sample(c(1:10000), 1250)
simulated.ds$var1[ind1] <- NA

set.seed(150)
ind2 <- sample(c(1:10000), 1250)
simulated.ds$var2[ind2] <- NA

set.seed(1000)
ind5 <- sample(c(1:10000), 1250)
simulated.ds$var5[ind5] <- NA

set.seed(500)
ind6 <- sample(c(1:10000), 1250)
simulated.ds$var6[ind6] <- NA

write.csv(simulated.ds, "rawDataR.csv", row.names = F)

prepRoutine <- caret::preProcess(simulated.ds, method = "knnImpute", k=5)
imputed_dataset <- predict(prepRoutine, simulated.ds)

write.csv(imputed_dataset, "imputedDataR.csv", row.names = F)
```

When I preprocess the same simulated dataset by trying to replicate the imputation process in Python 3 using the code below, the results from the imputed dataset are different.

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

rawDataR = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/AfrikanaScholar/Documents/rawDataR.csv")
imputedDataR = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/AfrikanaScholar/Documents/imputedDataR.csv")

random.seed(197)
scaler = StandardScaler()
imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5, weights="distance")

data_pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('scaler', scaler),
    ('imputer', imputer)
])

imputedDataPy = data_pipeline.fit_transform(rawDataR)

dataPy = pd.DataFrame(imputedDataPy).round(3)
dataR = imputedDataR.round(3) 

np.array_equal(dataR.values, dataPy.values)
>> ***False***
```

My questions are:

1. Why would the different platforms, taking the same approach, using the same data, produce such differences? For example, using the imputed values from the 5th column,

   From python 3:

   ```
    Counter({
      -1.522: 2644,
      -1.086: 55,
      -0.65: 193,
      -0.215: 485,
       0.221: 478,
       0.398: 1,
       0.657: 6144        
       })
   ```

   From R:

   ```
        -1.522 -1.086  -0.65 -0.215  0.221  0.657 
         2638      3    222    272    582   6283
   ```
2. What could be done to ensure that the values between the different platforms are as similar as possible?

Such discrepancies would make the modelling process produce varying findings across different platforms.

Answer (score 4):

This is obviously less than ideal.

Let's wait with your broad empirical comparison and do simple specific comparison.

I'll work with `iris` just to keep things simple.

Lets scale and compare:

### R

```r
x <- as.matrix( iris[,1:4] )
write.csv( x, "~/iris.csv", row.names=FALSE )

x_scaled = scale(x)

x[1,]
```

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  -0.8976739    1.0156020   -1.3357516   -1.3110521
```

### Python

```py
x = pd.read_csv("iris.csv")
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(x)
x_scaled[:1]
```

```
>>> x_scaled[:1]
array([[-0.90068117,  1.01900435, -1.34022653, -1.3154443 ]])
```

*They can't even scale data correctly across platforms!*

At this point bells might be ringing.

Because the *centered* data do match:

**R**:

```r
> scale(x,scale=FALSE)[1,]
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  -0.7433333    0.4426667   -2.3580000   -0.9993333
```

**Py**:

```py
>>> centerer = StandardScaler( with_std=False )
>>> x_centered = centerer.fit_transform(x)
>>> x_centered[:1]
array([[-0.74333333,  0.44266667, -2.358     , -0.99933333]])
```

And if you do the biased standard deviation in R, you now do get matching values:

**R**:

```
> x_centered <- scale( x_orig, scale=FALSE )
> sweep( x_centered, 2, sqrt( apply(x_orig,2,var) * (n-1)/n ), FUN="/" ) %>% head(n=1)
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]   -0.9006812    1.019004    -1.340227   -1.315444
```

These are the scaled values python produced too!

### KNN imputation wihtout scaling differences

Let's introduce a NA in the first row:

```r
x_withNA <- x_scaled
x_withNA[1,2] <- NA
write.csv( x_withNA, "~/iris_withNA.csv", row.names=FALSE )
```

In R:

```
> prepRoutine <- caret::preProcess(x_withNA, method = "knnImpute", k=5)
> predict(prepRoutine, x_withNA)[1,]
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  -0.8976739    1.0225507   -1.3357516   -1.3110521
```

In Py (reading prescaled data from R):

```
>>> x_withNA = pd.read_csv("iris_withNA.csv")
>>> imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=5)
>>> x_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(x_withNA)
>>> x_imputed[:1]
array([[-0.89767388,  1.01560199, -1.33575163, -1.31105215]])
```

Still not there, but perhaps getting closer.

### caret::knnImpute does scaling its own way

See [this code](https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/pkg/caret/R/preProcess.R#L513). In short, caret scales data after removing incomplete cases, before doine knn imputation with them.

So this line here:

```
prepRoutine <- caret::preProcess(x_withNA, method = "knnImpute", k=5)
```

crates an object where the reference data (x_withNA) used for knn is scaled with NA rows removed, which is also different from python aparently.

So let's trick caret, let's inject *our* scaled reference data, and throw out *his*!

```r
prepRoutine$data <- x_withNA[-1,]
predict(prepRoutine, x_withNA)[1,]
```

And Lo and Behold! - from R now:

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
  -0.8976739    1.0156020   -1.3357516   -1.3110521
```

And just pasting those from Python way up:

```
array([[-0.89767388,  1.01560199, -1.33575163, -1.31105215]])
```

That has to pass for a match!

### Conclusion

This particular case, with a single NA, fails to produce equal results due to a few really subtle differences in design philosophy:

1. **python** scales with population standard deviation sqrt(sum(x-u)/n).
2. **R/caret** scales with sample standard deviation sqrt(sum(x-u)/(n-1)).
3. **python** scales based on data from incomplete and complete rows.
4. **R/caret** scales using data only from complete rows.

It should come as no surprise that these pecularities weren't particularly well documented in either libraries' manuals.

But do things the same way, and numbers will add up.

---

**A slightly confusing observation**

The imputed value gets to have the exact same value, to the vert smallest 20th decimal or so. Which is suspicious. This is beacuse my choice of data was unwise in that regard. The iris data only have one decimal precision.

The row that has its *Sepal.Width* imputed is this, `3.5` being the value that gets removed:

```
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
         5.1          3.5          1.4          0.2
```

The 5 nearest neighbours are these:

```
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
[1,]          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2
[2,]          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2
[3,]          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2
[4,]          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
[5,]          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2
```

Incidently these neighbours have an average value of *Sepal.Width* that is exactly `3.5`, spot on what the simulated missing value is.

Had I known this in advance, I would have added small amounts of noise to the data.

I am not redoing all this now.